# What is the deep link URL to open Square POS app from within another app?

Tags: square, square-connect

For example in order to open Venmo from within my app I would use `Linking.openURL('venmo://')` which would subsequently pop open Venmo on the device, leaving my app in the process.

What, if it exists, is the URL for the Square Point of Sale app?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs for the Point of Sale APIs, they have all that is possible with link building int the app. It is only for payments, you can't link into other views.

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/point-of-sale-api-overview